# How Windows Explorer FTPs a Linux Server

Tags: linux, windows-explorer, ftp

I just discovered that Windows Explorer can act as a simple FTP client, and used it (instead of my "norm" - FileZilla) to FTP into my linux server.

I am wondering if Samba plays any role in this - otherwise, how would my Windows FTP client be able to communicate with a Linux server?

If this is the case, when FTPed into my Linux server, can I treat the open Window Explorer instance as if it were a Windows machine? For instance if I wanted to unzip a ZIP file on the server, would I be able to just right-click it as normal, or would I need a Linux equivalent to ZIP/TAR installed on the machine in order for the Unzip command to work?

Comment: From a windows perspective the ftp-server is just a network drive with restricted privileges.

Comment: By implementing the FTP RFC: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc959.txt

Comment: ftp has nothing to do with smb or nmb protocol

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I am wondering if Samba plays any role in this - otherwise, how would my Windows FTP client be able to communicate with a Linux server?

Windows Explorer simply has a built-in FTP ("File Transfer Protocol" - a protocol that handles file transfers all by itself) client - that is how it's communicating. Samba is not involved if the connection is explicitly through FTP.

> For instance if I wanted to unzip a ZIP file on the server, would I be able to just right-click it as normal, or would I need a Linux equivalent to ZIP/TAR installed on the machine in order for the Unzip command to work?

If you right-click and unzip, your Windows machine would *read* the contents by downloading the file over FTP, then unzip it *to* the FTP site, so if you had write permissions: yes, you could unzip things this way.

It will, however, involve a file transfer to the Windows machine of the compressed data, and then an upload to the Linux machine of the uncompressed data, so you'd be much better off simply using [PuTTY](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/) as an SSH client and running `unzip` directly on the Linux machine.

*Disclaimer:* I don't even know if the built-in FTP client supports uploading over FTP. Don't think I've ever used that functionality, and haven't been on Windows for a long time, but a quick net search seems to indicate that it does indeed support uploading.